# Trying to fit f distribution to a vector

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

Would anyone know why the following code fails to execute `fitdist` with error "the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, with the error code 100". 
I have encountered this error in the past when working with the normal distribution; the solution in that case was increasing the variance of the vector (by multiplying it by say 100), but that does not help on this case. Please note all elements in the vector are positive. Thank you.

```
library(fitdistrplus)
VH <- c(0.36, 0.3, 0.36, 0.47, 0, 0.05, 0.4, 0, 0, 0.15, 0.89, 0.03,  0.45, 0.21, 0, 0.18, 0.04, 0.53, 0, 0.68, 0.06, 0.09, 0.58, 0.03, 0.23, 0.27, 0, 0.12, 0.12, 0, 0.32, 0.07, 0.04, 0.07, 0.39, 0, 0.25, 0.28, 0.42, 0.55, 0.04, 0.07, 0.18, 0.17, 0.06, 0.39, 0.65, 0.15, 0.1, 0.32, 0.52, 0.55, 0.71, 0.93, 0, 0.36)
f <- fitdist(na.exclude(VH),"f", start =list(df1=1, df2=2))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you get here is actually somewhat informative:

> simpleError in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,     ddistnam = ddistname, hessian = TRUE, method = meth, lower = lower,     upper = upper, ...): function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters
>
> Error in fitdist(na.exclude(VH), "f", start = list(df1 = 1, df2 = 2)) : 
>     the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
>                   with the error code 100

That means something went wrong right away, not in the middle of the optimization process.

Taking a guess, I looked and saw that there was a zero value in your data (so your statement that all the elements are positive is not technically correct -- they're all *non-negative* ...). The F distribution has an infinite value at 0: `df(0,1,2)` is `Inf`.

If I exclude the zero value, I get an answer ...

```
f <- fitdist(na.exclude(VH[VH>0]),"f", start =list(df1=1, df2=2))
```

... the estimated value for the second shape parameter is very large (approx. 6e6, with a big uncertainty), but seems to fit OK ...

```
par(las=1); hist(VH,freq=FALSE,col="gray")
curve(df(x,1.37,6.45e6),add=TRUE)
```

[image]